# jQuery : Passing a method directly to the on event handler isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am making a simple notification with a close button that should fade it out:

```
  this.close.on("click",this.clear);

  }

  Notification.prototype.clear = function(){
    this.node.fadeOut();

  };
```

however when I click it it throws this exception "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fadeOut' of undefined "

I tried passing a function expression that calls the clear method and it worked.

so my question is why didn't it work the first time but worked the second one.

Comment: is `this.node` a jQuery object?

Comment: yes it is a jQuery object

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the jquery object as follows:

```
$(this.node).fadeOut();
```

Provided node represents a DOM object this will use the jquery to fade out the object.